# Аналог RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Всем доброго времени суток. Появилась следующая задача.

У меня есть прокручиваемые `CardView`, в одном из которых мне нужно разместить **сетку** с thumbnail'ами. В конце находится кнопка для добавления новых. Мне так же нужна интеграция адаптеров, так как для каждой картинки нужен свой лейаут, а не один только `ImageView`.

Прикрепляю скриншот, что бы можно было легче понять, как должно все выглядеть. Пока я использую `HorizontalScrollView`. Вместо него должен быть какой-то другой `View`, который схож с `RecyclerView`, либо даже он сам, если можно как-то его настроить под мою задачу.
Если посоветуете через какую-либо библиотеку - то хотелось бы сразу пример кода увидеть.

[image: Дизайн готового варианта. HorizontalScroll и дочерние элементы - на замену]

UPD: Пока что приходится изобретать велосипед - в вертикальный `LinearLayout` вставляю горизонтальные и сам написал код, который будет определять, сколько будет столбцов, в зависимости от размера экрана. Проблема - картинки за пределами экрана все равно отрисовываются, из-за чего нагружают железо. Думаю, все таки должна быть библиотека, где все это уже изобретено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `RecyclerView` c горизонтальной ориентацией в `LayoutManager`. Для разных типов `item`, используйте разные `layout` файлы. Выбор конкретного `layout` файла можно сделать у адаптера в методе

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return ;
    }
```

Этот тип вам придет в метод

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
             case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
             ...
         }
    }
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что мне нужно. Нужна именно **сетка**, как в `GridLayoutManager`, только она еще и прокручиваться не должна, так как **уже находится в `ScrollView`**. Просто временный выход - это прокрутка по горизонтали, а нужно, чтобы была сетка вниз без прокрутки.

Comment: Можно отключить скрол у recyclerview и тогда скролиться будет только scrollview

Comment: Ого, чет даже не думал, что так можно сделать. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, можно просто отключить скролл у `RecyclerView`.
[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling) узнал, как.

В моем случае, так:

```
 gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context) {
 @Override
 public boolean canScrollVertically() { return false; }};
```

Comment: Я думаю Вам @pavel163 ответил, можно его ответ принять